# How to find array difference in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$give_ans = Array ( [0] =>0 [1] => 0[2] =>0 [3] =>0 [4] => 0[5] =>0 [6] =>1 [7] =>2 [8] => [9] =>4 [10] => 3[11] =>1 [12] => 0[13] => 2[14] => 1[15] =>2 [16] =>0 [17] =>0 )
```

and

```
$correct_Ans = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 2 [8] => 2 [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 [14] => 2 [15] => 2 [16] => 2 [17] => 2 )
```

From these two array, I want to check that if the elements of the same index of the both array are equal then they should be put into one array.

If the element in `give_ans` array is 0 then they should be put into another array

and the remaining elements should be put into the third array.

How can I achieve this please help me ?

Comment: can you provide the array in correct format

Comment: ... so what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Are the given arrays always using the very same indexes? Or is it possible one can differ from another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$given_ans = array(0 => 0, 1 => 0,2 =>0 , 3 =>0 ,4 => 0, 5 =>0 , 6 =>1 ,7 =>2 ,8 => 1,9 =>4 , 10 => 3,11 =>1 ,12 => 0,13 => 2,14 => 1,15 =>2 ,16 =>0 ,17 =>0 );
$correct_ans = array(0 => 3 ,1 => 1 ,2 => 4 ,3 => 2 ,4 => 3 ,5 => 2 ,6 => 1 ,7 => 2 ,8 => 2 ,9 => 2 ,10 => 2 ,11 => 2 ,12 => 2 ,13 => 2 ,14 => 2 ,15 => 2 ,16 => 2 ,17 => 2 );

$count = count($given_ans);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($given_ans[$i] == 0) {
        $zero_ans[$i] = $given_ans[$i];
        unset($given_ans[$i]);
    } else if ($given_ans[$i] == $correct_ans[$i]) {
        $result_ans[$i] = $given_ans[$i];
        unset($given_ans[$i]);
    }
}
echo "Zero value:";
print_r($zero_ans);
echo "Correct:";
print_r($result_ans);
echo "Remaining:";
print_r($given_ans);
```

Here working: [link](https://eval.in/86735)

$result_ans will now contain both key and value of matching indexes/values; $zero_ans will contain $given_ans 0 values; $given_ans will contain remaining values.

If you don't want $given_ans to be erased, you can always make a copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$length = count($given_ans);
$result = array();

for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
     if ($given_ans[$i] == $correct_Ans[$i]) {
         $result[] = $given_ans[$i];
     }
}
```

Working demo https://eval.in/86693

Answer (score 1):

function array_diff will help you here:

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

But you want to index all the duplicate contents so simply do for loop:

```
$equalResult = array();
for($c = 0; $c < count($give_ans); $c++) {
    if(isset($give_ans[$c]) && isset($correct_Ans[$c])) {
        if($give_ans[$c] == $correct_Ans[$c]) {
            $equalResult[] = array($give_ans[$c] => $correct_Ans[$c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $give_ans = array(0 => 0, 1 => 0,2 =>0 , 3 =>0 ,4 => 0, 5 =>0 , 6 =>1 ,7 =>2 ,8 => 1,9 =>4 , 10 => 3,11 =>1 ,12 => 0,13 => 2,14 => 1,15 =>2 ,16 =>0 ,17 =>0 );
  $correct_Ans = Array (0 => 3 ,1 => 1 ,2 => 4 ,3 => 2 ,4 => 3 ,5 => 2 ,6 => 1 ,7 => 2 ,8 => 2 ,9 => 2 ,10 => 2 ,11 => 2 ,12 => 2 ,13 => 2 ,14 => 2 ,15 => 2 ,16 => 2 ,17 => 2 );

  print_r(array_diff($give_ans, $correct_Ans));
```

Returns an array of elements that don't match

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [12] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 )
```

Comment: Read the question first. `From these two array, I want to check that if the elements of the same index of the both array are equal then they should be put into one array.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this logic

```
$result = array();

foreach($give_ans as $key => $value){
    if($give_ans[$key] == $correct_Ans[$key]){
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray  = array();
$nullArray = array();
$tempArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($give_ans) ; $i++){
   if (($give_ans[$i] === $correct_ans[$i]) && $give_ans !== 0){
      array_push($newArray, $give_ans[$i]);
      array_push($tempArray, $i);
   }else if ($give_ans[$i] === 0){
      array_push($nullArray, $i);
      array_push($tempArray, $i);
   }
}

$othersArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($give_ans); $i++){
   if ($tempArray[$i] !== $give_ans[$i])
      array_push($othersArray, $give_ans[$i];
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($correct_ans); $i++){
   if ($tempArray[$i] !== $correct_ans[$i])
      array_push($othersArray, $correct_ans[$i];
}
```

I've got no time to test it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) function.

Comment: It will not help to check if values  are same in the same index.